# How to set Cell Background Color in GoogleSpreadsheet Using AppScript Project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

App Script Code

```
var spreadSheet = e.source;
var range = e.range;
var column = range.getColumn();
var row = range.getRow();
var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(row, 2).getValue();
if( column==3 && value=='')
{
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(row, 1).setBackgroundRGB(red);
}
```

In output I am only getting font color as red.

Comment: try .setBackgroundRGB(255,0,0) instead of .setBackgroundRGB(red)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `.setBackground("#f9cb9c")`

Example:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
function setBgColor() {
  sheet.getRange('A1:C1').setBackground("#f9cb9c");
  sheet.getRange('A2:C2').setBackground("#b6d7a8");
  sheet.getRange('A3:C3').setBackground("#a4c2f4");
}
```

[image]